# MySQL performance: Extending Table Columns or Creating Reference Table

Tags: mysql

I need to create a flexible stats table where different stats are tied to different sports and then the actual stat is stored for each player in a league. I have created two methods but cannot figure out which is the better approach.

I have read posts on similar topics but few combine the flexibility i need and the bredth i require for both storing and then analyzing stats.

Globally speaking we expect to manage 50,000-100,000 players ranging across 50 sports with about 20 stats per sport over the next 10 years.

In both scenarios the company staff may add a stat occasionally but rarely adds new sports. Every thing is managed by a back-end interface. Since sports however can be added I did not think a middle ground approach was good where a sport_stats table is created when a new sport is added and each players data is kept in the relative sports table with a column for each stat in that sport.

The primary method was creating the stats in a single table which held the sport and relative attributes and then having a player table that had a column for each stat to hold all the data. This meant that there are potentially tons of empty columns since a player only plays a specific sport and there could be 15-20 stats per sport and about 30,000 players.

meaning 30,000 records with tons of null data and useless fields

---

### table stats

id  |  sport  |  type  |  name  |  atrribs

---

### table players_stats

id  |  stat_1  |  stat_2  |  stat_n (grows when any stat added)

Then I thought of an idea where there is still the same stats table but then there is a values table that simply holds the stat,player,value and I would then gather all stats for a specific player getting only what they filled out

meaning no empty fields but potentially a few million entries over the next 10 years of expected user data.

---

### table stats

id  |  sport  |  type  |  name  |  atrribs

---

### table stats_data

id  |  player_id  |  stat_id  |  vale

...gets really big real quick

Comment: If we consider option 2, then you have 20 stats on 100,000 players logged say once a week for 10 years. That's a billion rows, which isn't even worth worrying about - even less so in 10 years' time.

Comment: apologies for not being clear. we expect only 100,000 users over the next 10 years each which will only have a value for about 50 stats since they only play one or two sports, so i expect more like 5 million rows in 10 years

Comment: Well even less reason to worry then!

Comment: Your last table implements the [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). 5M rows is nothing that my smartphone couldn't handle.